# How to create an array with Object that has private copy constructor

Tags: c++, private-constructor

I have a struct that have some member and a Object that have private copy constructor, How can I create an array that include this object.
For example:
I have an Object:

```
class Image
{
   ...
   private:
      Image(const Image&);
      Image& operator=(const Image&);
      u8* pixel;
      int width;
      int height
}

struct ImageInformation
{
   Image image;
   int resolution;
}
```

I want to create an array for ImageInformation : vector but this is forbidding

Comment: Are you trying to create a C-style array, a `std::array`, or a `std::vector`? Maybe provide a bit more code that includes the line that triggers the error?

Comment: What constructors are public?

Comment: `std::vectror` and it's `emplace` functions should be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to define the `move ctor` and `move assignment operator` on the `Image` `class` since the default implementations would be deleted because you provided a user declared `copy ctor` and `copy assignment operator`.

You should then be able to use the `vector` with no issue.

```
class Image
{
public:
    Image( int height, int width ) 
        : height_{ height }
        , width_{ width }
    { }

    Image( Image&& ) = default;
    Image& operator=( Image&& ) = default;

    Image( const Image& ) = delete;
    Image& operator=( const Image& ) = delete;

private:
    int height_;
    int width_;
};

class ImageInformation
{
public:
    explicit ImageInformation( Image image )
        : image_{ std::move( image ) }
    { }

private:
    Image image_;
};


int main( )
{
    std::vector<ImageInformation> containers;

    Image image{ 10, 10 };
    containers.emplace_back( std::move( image ) );
}
```